# Display Duplicates SQL with Where

Tags: sql, t-sql

i have 2 two tables,

```
 Invoice (ordernumber, status(which assign to InvoiceStatuses), etc)
```

and

```
InvoiteStatuses(status name, statusid)
```

i need to check duplicates in Invoice only for OrderNumber, but `where status != statusID` (where name is "CANCELLED")

```
SELECT A.*
FROM Invoices A
JOIN InvoiceStatuses b 
 (
   SELECT * FROM InvoiceStatuses  
   WHERE InvoiceStatus = 'CANCELLED'
 ) B
ON A.InvoiceStatus!=b.InvoiceStatusID
WHERE exists (SELECT OrderNumber
    FROM Invoices c
    WHERE a.OrderNumber = c.OrderNumber
    GROUP BY OrderNumber
    HAVING COUNT(*)>1)
```

Comment: Please write a textual description of what you want done, instead of just writing the words you want in the WHERE clause in English. It isn't entirely clear what you want to do here.

Comment: Do you have a primary key column in your `invoices` table?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to make the following change in your query

The JOIN clause filters the cancelled status out and where clause to retrieve only duplicate

```
SELECT A.*
FROM Invoices A
WHERE exists (SELECT OrderNumber
              FROM Invoices c
                 JOIN InvoiceStatuses b 
                 ON c.InvoiceStatus=b.InvoiceStatusID 
                    AND InvoiceStatus != 'CANCELLED'
              WHERE a.OrderNumber = c.OrderNumber
              GROUP BY OrderNumber
              HAVING COUNT(*)>1)
```

Comment: this will return record as duplicate even if there are no other records that match - `InvoiceStatus != 'CANCELLED'`

Comment: but if i have for example: two invoices with same number but one is canceled second no - i dont need to show it. on ur query its shows

Comment: I have updated the query. Can you check if this works?